# displaying thumbnail image multiple times within listview/repeater itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview, repeater

if I want to display e.g. up to 50 records on a page using a listview/(or repeater), and an ItemTemplate within the listview or repeater contains a thumbnail of a user, is there a best way to do this? I'm just thinking of page load time and the time it takes to load each image...

Could the image be loaded once, make each time it appears a copy of one that is already on the page?

Is this possible or is there a best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to see what the performance is like? You may be surprised.

Comment: ha yeah I've just tried it on my development laptop and yeah it was actually pretty quick...50*50 thunbmail...seemed to go ok.

Comment: The reason I asked is because I did something like this recently, with images around 30k and 200x80, works fine for me. I probably wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Ok cool. If you put that in an answer I'll tick it:)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this recently, with images around 30k and 200x80, worked fine for me. Images will be cached after the first load, so I probably wouldn't worry about it.